# Creating sign-in with my site functionality

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

We need to develop feature on our site "project.net" for our partners' sites like google sign-in but with our users.
The main idea is that partner adds button: "sign-in with project.net".
I already have FOSOAuthServerBundle but I can't understand how to implement such feature.
How is such idea called?

Thank you

Comment: It's called single sign-on, but anyway this is not a Code Request website, I'd highly suggest you to read the FAQs of StackOverflow and come back with a properly setup question.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, I'm asking for any documentation!

Comment: It's not the place to ask for it, I am sorry. StackOverflow is only for code-related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. Like @GiamPy said it's called single sign-on.
There is a bundle for symfony called: korotovsky/sso-idp-bundle:~0.2.0